# Kivy for android: video can't load by opencv on the phone

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy

I have already packaged Opencv with kivy to android and the face detection with the camera works fine. But I can't load the video by OpenCV.

I was trying to manipulate the frames from an `mp4` in android through OpenCV. It works on PC, but can't load files from android by `cv2.VideoCapture("test.mp4")`.

I found that the `Videoplayer` is using texture, too. We can access the texture by `VideoPlayer._video.texture`. So technically, it is possible to manipulate the frames with OpenCV like draw a rectangular on the face or etc. But I don't know how to achieve it.

So, how can I load the video and pipe it to OpenCV or Read it with Opencv directly?

my requirements are:

```
requirements = kivy==2.0.0, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,
  openssl, requests, Urllib3, chardet, certifi, idna,
  numpy, pillow==8.0.0, opencv, ffmpeg, ffpyplayer, ffpyplayer_codecs,
  opencc-python-reimplemented, docutils, android,
  sqlite3, lxml, cymunk, pyjnius, twisted, plyer
```

adblog：

```
05-24 21:59:34.749 13052 13118 F libc    : Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0xc6691a01 in tid 13118 (SDLThread), pid 13052 (test.karobbentb)
05-24 21:59:34.834 13209 13209 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 13052 (target tid = 13118)
05-24 21:59:35.263 13052 13052 V PythonActivity: onPause()
05-24 21:59:35.263 13052 13052 V SDL     : onPause()
05-24 21:59:35.263 13052 13052 V SDL     : nativePause()
05-24 21:59:35.273 13052 13052 V SDL     : onWindowFocusChanged(): false
05-24 21:59:35.273 13052 13052 D DecorView: showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=false; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
```

Comment: Did you add mp4 file type to "source.include_exts =" line in buildozer.spec?

Comment: Thx. I'm not reading videos from the root directory. I am reading pictures and videos from cellphone storage. I can pack images to video with cv, which means my path is correct and other functions work fine. But it immediately crashed when I tried read videos by `cv2.VideoCapture`